# Angular 6 CLI Generate Service Command not registering in app.module

Tags: command-line-interface, angular6

I recently upgraded my Angular 4 to 6
Now project is working fine but when i run below command to generate the service, service got generated but it is not registered in app.module.ts

```
C:\Users\my-project>ng g s security/security --module app

C:\Users\my-project>ng g s security/security --module=app
```

[image]

Comment: The ng g s don't have a --module ( -m ) option in Angular 6.                                      
 ng g s --help doesn't list --module option.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, I think maybe the quote from version 6 release notes explains why?

https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4 - "To make your applications smaller, we’ve moved from modules referencing services to services referencing modules. This allows us to only bundle services into your code base in modules where they are injected."